# Creating a sub_lists from a list

Tags: python, list

I have a Training_list, its a list of lists e.g.

```
[[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,'<50k'],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,'<50k'],
 [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,'>50k'],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,'>50k'],
 [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,'<50k'],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,'>50k'],
 ...
]
```

I'm trying to sub divide this list into two sub_lists based on the last attribute. 
The first list should contain an under_50k list of lists for all the <50k records e.g.

```
[[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13], [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13], ...]
```

The second list should contain an over_50k list of lists for all the >50k records e.g.

```
[[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13], [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13], ...]
```

Once both lists are created I'm then trying to add up each index for the lists
e.g.

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13] + [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13]
= [2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26]
```

Can seem to get the subdivision of the lists to work thou.

```
def sums_list():

    sums_list = []
    try:
        for index in range(15):
            sums_list.append(under_50k_list[index]+over_50k_list[index])
    except:
        pass
        return(sums_list)

def under_over_lists():

    under_50k_list = [0]*14
    under_50k_count = 0
    over_50k_list = [0]*14
    over_50k_count = 0
    try:
        for row in training_list:
            if row[-1].lstrip() == '<=50K':
                under_50k_list = sums_list(under_50k_list, row[:-1])
                under_50k_count += 1
            else:
                if row[-1].lstrip() == '>50K':
                    over_50k_list = sums_list(over_50k_list, row[:-1])
                    over_50k_count += 1
    except:
        pass
        print(under_50k_list)
        return under_over_lists
```

Comment: You should provide additional tags, e.g. what programming language this is.

Comment: sorry, i'm new to stack overflow, its python

Comment: Do you actually want the intermediate lists, or just the result?

Comment: @saggart , your logic is correct, however, code in your post contains great amount of errors. Try to remove ```try except``` and fix them.

Comment: Hi Useless, i'm looking to be able to print both the under and over lists

Answer (score 0):

You can use `numpy` if every sub-list of a `list` is of same size

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> llist=[[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,'<50k'],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,'<50k'], [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,'>50k'],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,'>50k'],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,'<50k'],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,'>50k']]
>>> under_50k_list=[i[:-1] for i in llist if i[-1]=='<50k']
>>> under_50k_list
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]]
>>> over_50k_list=[i[:-1] for i in llist if i[-1]=='>50k']
>>> over_50k_list
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]]
>>> sum(np.array(under_50k_list))
array([ 3,  6,  9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27, 30, 33, 36, 39])
>>> under_50k_sum=sum(np.array(under_50k_list))
>>> over_50k_sum=sum(np.array(over_50k_list))
>>> under_50k_sum
array([ 3,  6,  9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27, 30, 33, 36, 39])
>>> over_50k_sum
array([ 3,  6,  9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27, 30, 33, 36, 39])
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `append` method to get your subdivision to work properly.  I feel it is more friendly to a dynamic sized list.

```
over_50k = []
under_50k = []
for row in training_list:
    if row[-1] == "<50k":
        under_50k.append(row[:-1])
    elif row[-1] == ">50k":
        over_50k.append(row[:-1])
```

Now to get your sums:

```
over_50k_sum = [i for i in over_50k[0]]  # initialize with the first one
for i in range(1,len(over_50k)):         # skips the first one
    for j in range(len(over_50k[i])):
        over_50k_sum[j] += over_50k[i][j]

under_50k_sum = [i for i in under_50k[0]]  # initialize with the first one
for i in range(1,len(under_50k)):          # skips the first one
    for j in range(len(under_50k[i])):
        under_50k_sum[j] += under_50k[i][j]
```

Comment: [37, 0.7173543689320389, None, None, 9, 0.3351132686084142, 0.05165857605177993, 0.2942961165048544, 0.8373381877022654, 0.6119741100323625, 0, 0, 45, None, ' <=50K'], [46, 0.7173543689320389, None, None, 13, 0.03673139158576052, 0.13199838187702265, 0.3013349514563107, 0.8373381877022654, 0.38802588996763754, 0, 0, 25, None, ' <=50K'], [44, 0.7173543689320389, None, None, 9, 0.1610032362459547, 0.12823624595469255, 0.3013349514563107, 0.8373381877022654, 0.6119741100323625, 0, 0, 40, None, ' >50K'],

Comment: Hi Joe, i tried your code;     over_50k = []
    under_50k = []

    for row in training_list:
        print("u")
        if row[-1].lstrip() == '<=50K':
            print("a")
            under_50k.append(row[:-1])
            print("b")
        else:
            if row[-1].lstrip() == '>50K':
                over_50k.append(row[:-1])

Comment: It doesnt seem to create the over & under lists, i tried adding print statements below - row in training_list, also below if row[-1].lstrip() == '<=50K': & if row[-1].lstrip() == '>50K': They all print out, not sure what the problem is, i included above a bit of the output from my actual training list

Comment: @saggart It works fine on my computer.  I noticed however that you have `"<=50"`  but in the example data you provided you had `"<50"`, could this be causing the error?  I also do not see how you ended up with output you provided.  The sample data you gave is all integers, how did you end up with numbers less than 1?

Comment: @saggart I took screen shots, you should be able to properly adapt my suggestions from them: http://imgur.com/a/jXfYw

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you only want the result, and not the intermediate lists, it's just:

```
ll = [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,'<50k'], ... ]

sumlist = lambda a,b:[x+y for x,y in zip(a,b)]
def sum_if(lists, key):
    return reduce(sumlist, (l[:-1] for l in lists if l[-1]==key))

under_50k_count = sum_if(ll, '<50k')
over_50k_count = sum_if(ll, '>50k')
```

It might be worth importing `ìzip from itertools` and using that instead of `zip` if your lists are long and you want to reduce copying, but it certainly isn't essential.

Answer (score 0):

Because one-liners are fun:

```
ll = [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,'<50k'], ...]
under_50k_count = [sum(b) for b in zip(*[a[:-1] for a in ll if a[-1].startswith('<')])]
over_50k_count = [sum(b) for b in zip(*[a[:-1] for a in ll if a[-1].startswith('>')])]
```

That in itself is not a useful stack overflow answer, falling into the category of "try this" with no explanation, so let's break it down a little.

We use a list comprehension to separate out the 2 different kinds of lists:

```
[a[:-1] for a in ll if a[-1].startswith('<')]
```

we then [unpack](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#tut-unpacking-arguments) this list and pass it to zip, which provides us with a list of tuples:

```
[(1,1,1,...), (2,2,2,...), ...]
```

We then use another list comprehension to sum each of these tuples.

List comprehensions are obviously fast, unpacking lists is not (especially for large lists). So, while it is kind of fun to compress things like this, I wouldn't recommend using it if speed is any concern or if there is even a remote possibility of anyone inheriting you code.